# Comparing high and low values to call a function

Tags: c, function, structure

I want to compare the current in my temperature sensor with the high limit value that i have set in the program using structures. If the temperature sensor valued exceeds the current high limit I would just like to `printf` a statement.

What is wrong with this code, it never prints out the `printf` statement no matter what the current temperature is. Please presume that all necessary header files, definitions etc are stated in the program.

It works fine as a whole, but I don't get why i can't get a simple `printf` command to show up!! Please assume that all needed definitions have been made, and all `typedef`s accordingly.

Here is my structure

```
struct temperatureChannel_t { //set a structure that encompasses all of the follow elements in an array
    temperature_t temperatureArray;
    temperature_t temperatures[MAXSAMPLES];
    temperature_t currentTemperature;
    temperature_t lowLimit;
    temperature_t highLimit;
    temperature_t minTemperature;
    temperature_t maxTemperature;

};

struct temperatureChannel_t temperatureChannel[MAXCHANNELS];
```

Here is how I initialize the current high limit

```
void initializeTemperatureSubsystem()
{
    currentInsertionPoint = 0;
    for(int chID = 0; chID < MAXCHANNELS; chID++)
    {
            srand(time(NULL));
            for(int i = 1; i < MAXSAMPLES; i++)
            {   
                    temperatureChannel[chID].temperatures[i] = rand()%100;
            }
            temperatureChannel[chID].lowLimit = 50;
        temperatureChannel[chID].highLimit = 100;
        temperatureChannel[chID].currentTemperature = 75;

        averageIsValid = FALSE; //NEW line  
    }

}
```

here is how i am setting the current temperature, first the call to the function

```
setCurrentTemperature(CH1, temperatureSensor1Reading);
```

then the function

```
temperature_t setCurrentTemperature(int channelID, temperature_t temperature)
{
    return temperatureChannel[channelID].currentTemperature;
}
```

First i have my call to the function, with the current channel I am using

```
compareHighLimit(CH1);
```

**Then here's the function that won't print out a printf command**

```
void compareHighLimit (int channelID)
{
    if (temperatureChannel[channelID].currentTemperature > temperatureChannel[channelID].highLimit)
            printf("you have activated the high alarm!!");  
}
```

Comment: Print the values in the `compareHighLimit()` function (the conditions in your `if(...)` statement) for an input that you think should cause the `printf()` to work. Are the values what you expect?

Comment: it triggers if i use compareHighLimit(CH1, CH1Reading) and then call CH1 reading into my function and compare it from there...but that's not the point of my exercise...I should be able to determine CH1 reading from just using the single CH1 value, which should call its current temperature from the structure respectively.

Comment: I understand. When a conditional doesn't do what you want it to, a good practice is to see what it is actually comparing by printing the values. As the answers below indicate, it is likely that doing so would show you that you never set the temperature. :)

Comment: you're right d0rmlife....i realized i only returned currentTemperature without setting it...thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your set temp function doesn't actually set the value:

```
temperature_t setCurrentTemperature(int channelID, temperature_t temperature)
{
    // you need to set the data here, not just return the existing  value
    return temperatureChannel[channelID].currentTemperature;
}
```

Comment: you're awesome chue.....thank you so much for your response...i made the necessary changes and now it works.......thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you ever set the temperature. You said you call

```
setCurrentTemperature(CH1, temperatureSensor1Reading);
```

This, I assume, is supposed to set `CH1`'s temperature to `temperatureSensor1Reading`. This function, however, doesn't seem to change the temperature:

```
temperature_t setCurrentTemperature(int channelID, temperature_t temperature)
{
    return temperatureChannel[channelID].currentTemperature;
}
```

It appears that you may have mixed up the code for `setCurrentTemperature` and `getCurrentTemperature`?

Comment: in that respect you are right raptor...i believe my professor looked at my code and told me to change that when i was wondering why (becasue he told us to define that function as "get" initially)